# Run some code when the application is closed

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have to run some line of code when the app is closed by the user(Clicking recent apps and clearing the application ).

Comment: What methods have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

If You want to execute some functions before the app is closing You have to override `onDestroy()` in Your activity class.

[onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy())

> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it), or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the `isFinishing()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    // Here add functions which You want to call before closing app
}
```

---

[onSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

> This method is called before an activity may be killed so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

[Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#activity-lifecycle)

Comment: onDestroy() is called before the Activity is destroyed not after it

Comment: Yeah it is, but I think the questioner wants to execute some function generally when the app is closing and before or after destroy doesn't change anything

Comment: In android people generally kill the app by swiping up So I want to perform some operation when they kill the app

Comment: Also I used onDestory() but it is not working.

Comment: When the user "kill app by swapping" the 'onDestroy()' function is called. Also, You can try to override `onSaveInstanceState()`. It is called before an activity may be killed. So e.g. when the user swap app to the background and Your phone needs memory Your app will be killed by system.